# iPhone dev> Getting a CCSprite position from an other object in cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Hey people,
I'm creating a game in cocos2d, (I'm very new to it, and was trying to solve this thing)

in the game I'm making I created a "Bomb" class, and a "Player" class,
I want the bomb to check for collision with the player, if a collision detected, explode.

My problem is that I have no idea how to get the player's position from the bomb class,
I'd be happy if you guys could help me out here,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You did add the CCSprites to a CCLayer, didn't you? Then that CCLayer should have the access to both of them. So, you can use the CCLayer's `tick` function to track the positions of the CCSprites and trigger actions if their bounding boxes overlap.

Some sample code to illustrate:

```
@interface MyLayer : CCLayer {
  BombSprite *bomb;
  PlayerSprite *player;
}

...

@end

@implementation MyLayer

- (id)init {
   if ((self = [super init])) {
      bomb = ...
      player = ...

      [self schedule:@selector(tick:)];
   } 
   return self;
}

- (id)tick:(ccTime)dt {
   if (CGRectContainsRect([bomb boundingBox], [player boundingBox])) {
      NSLog(@"Collision!");

      // call [player didCollideWith:bomb] or something
      ...
   }
}

@end
```